# checkboxfor always return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have weird issue regarding binding a `checkboxfor`.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(TblCoordinators tb)    
{
    try
    {
        tb.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
      
        _context.TblCoordinators.Update(tb);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Data has been updated successfully");
       
        return PartialView("_Edit",ModelView);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Something went wrong.");
        return NoContent();
    }  
}
```

and in my view I have

```html
<form asp-action="Save"
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="POST"
      data-ajax-mode="replace"
      data-ajax-update="#edit"
      method="post">

    <div class="border">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h5 class="heading">Main Details</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row p-2">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].title" class="form-control" name="Title" required />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].coordinatorID" class="form-control" name="coordinatorID"  />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].created" class="form-control" name="created"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Contact Name
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].contactName" class="form-control" name="contactName" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Telephone
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].telephone" class="form-control" name="telephone" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Active
                            </label>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.infoList[0].active, new { @class= "form-check-input" })
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-50 ">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Address Line 1
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].addressLine1" class="form-control" name="addressLine1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                address Line 2
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].addressLine2" class="form-control" name="addressLine2" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                City
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].addressCity" class="form-control" name="addressCity" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                County
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].addressCounty" class="form-control" name="addressCounty" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Postcode
                            </label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].addressPostcode" class="form-control" name="addressPostcode" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am getting all data correct except the bool value for checkBox!!
I did a similar thing before for checkBox but in this case, I don't know why it is not working. Also, I have tried to get its value from this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="x" />
```

and in the controller like this :

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(TblCoordinators tb, bool x)
```

but it is still always false!!

Comment: Have you observed the rendered HTML?

Comment: let alone checkboxfor, why I can't bind it like this: <input type="checkbox" name="x" /> Save(TblCoordinators tb, bool x) ??

Comment: Hi @PariaShiri,any update about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the checkbox.

In `type=checkbox name=x`,If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on, so the submitted data in that case would be `x=on` instead of true or false.

You can see `checkbox` in [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

In your case,below is a simple demo.You can check it.

Model:

```
 public class info
{
    public string contactName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
}
public class TblCoordinators
{
    public List<info> infoList { get; set; }
}
```

Index View:

```
@model TblCoordinators

<form asp-action="Save" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
        Contact Name
    </label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].contactName" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
        Active
    </label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.infoList[0].active, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Action:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
      
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Save(TblCoordinators tb)
    {
        //....
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the thorough response, I know this way. Is there any way to rename the @Html.CheckBoxFor? or any way to catch it separately can't catch the object this way for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<input asp-for="@Model.infoList[0].active" class="form-control" name="active" />
```